# Erro ao adicionar classe em um elemento de uma nodelist

Tags: javascript

Meu objetivo é: quando clicar na div "job-card", o "job-resume" respectivo deveria aparecer, porém me retorna o erro "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.".

Não sei onde está o erro, podem dar uma olhada? Obrigado.

```
let jobCard = document.querySelectorAll('.job-card');
let jobResume = document.querySelectorAll('job-resume');
for(i = 0; i < jobCard.length;i++) {
    jobCard[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.classList.add('job-card-active');
        jobResume[i].classList.add('d-block');
    });
}
```

Comment: o seu `job-card` é o que ao certo ? tagname ? id? do que eu vi no seu codigo `document.querySelectorAll('.job-card');` tem o .job-card antes ou seja estas a procura de uma class?

Comment: Nessa linha let `jobResume = document.querySelectorAll('job-resume');` não está faltando um ponto no seletor `('.job-resume')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além do erro citado pelo @Augusto (falta do `.` no `querySelctorAll`) nos comentários, você terá um problema com a variável `i` dentro do seu `for`.

Quando você clicar sob um `div.job-card` o valor do `i` (dentro do `for`) será igual ao número de divs que tenham a classe `job-card`. Este é um problema clássico de [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) mas não vou entrar neste tema porque para o seu caso há uma alternativa mais simples, por exemplo, salvando o `i` em um `data-` attribute.

Montei um exemplo seguindo as informações que você deixou, espero que ajude:

```js
let jobCard = document.querySelectorAll('.job-card');
let jobResume = document.querySelectorAll('.job-resume');

/*
for(i = 0; i < jobCard.length; i++) {
    jobCard[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.add('job-card-active');
        console.log(i); // Execute este trecho e veja o valor do "i" quando clicar em um div
        jobResume[i].classList.add('d-block');
    });
}
*/

for(i = 0; i < jobCard.length; i++) {
  jobCard[i].setAttribute('data-i', i);
  
  jobCard[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    const idx = this.getAttribute('data-i');
    
    // Alterei o add pelo toggle
    this.classList.toggle('job-card-active');
    jobResume[idx].classList.toggle('d-block');
  });
}
```

```css
.job-card-active {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.d-block {
    display: block !important;
}

.job-resume {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="job-card">Item 1</div>
<div class="job-resume">Reumo 1</div>
<div class="job-card">Item 2</div>
<div class="job-resume">Reumo 2</div>
<div class="job-card">Item 3</div>
<div class="job-resume">Reumo 3</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado.